# Django: Polymorphic foreignkey relationships

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm developing kind of a social network in Django, but I don't see the way to maintain coupled my models.

I have a model `User`, which can comment on other Users, Pics, Pages (capitals are because they're models) via a `Comment` model. In order to arrange all that comments I created the Board model, that has one owner and receives all the comments addresed to that owner. The problem is I don't know how is its owner, i.e., which model does it belong to. It could be a pic's board, but also a user's one. So I end up with a model like this:

```
class Board(models.Model):
   category = models.IntegerField()
   owner_id = models.IntegerField()
```

I store owner's id and owner's category to be able to perform other tasks, but this solution doesn't convince me at all. A friend has advised me to use an abstract class `Board`, and then create a `UserBoard`, `PicBoard`, `PageBoard` which inherit from `Board`, but I think that will be useless too. I've thought about `GenericRelations`, but I'm not sure if that is the correct way to achieve what I'm trying. Any proposal will be listened and considered, thanks for your help :)

**PS:** Oh, and sorry if the title isn't very descriptive, but I couldn't figure out a better one. It's hard to explain this problem

Comment: see django manual for GenericForeignKey

Comment: There are third party app to improve polymorphism in django: https://www.djangopackages.com/grids/g/model-inheritance/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Option 1

Create a class `BoardOwner`. Have all models which have a board inherit from that, and have the board have a foreignkey relationship with `BoardOwner`. You'll need to then scan over the various childlinks to figure out which one is the "real" child. This more fiddly, but localises all of the complexity in one class.

## Option 2

Have a foreignkey from each class that has a board to the board. If you always have boards enter your system via a method on the owner (as opposed to a query on `Board` or elsewhere), you can have code in the owner which lets the `Board` know which foreign key reverse relationship to use. You'll probably want to factor that code into its own class.

## Option 3

Use `contenttypes`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/

This wraps up this sort of thing.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think I'll give it a try to option 3 :D